# Copying Google Files in Drive Using Terminal

Tags: terminal, google-drive

I use the terminal on Mac OSX to navigate my personal Google Drive folder. I stream files to my machine. I can navigate my files find, but have found that I cannot copy (`cp`) files. Is anyone aware of any documentation that can help me figure out why?

```
$ cp readings/unit_2_readings.gdoc readings/unit_3_readings.gdoc
cp: readings/unit_3_readings.gdoc: Invalid argument
$
```

It appears if I mirror all my files, I can use the `cp` command as expected. However, I would like to avoid mirroring files as there are maintenance implications I would need to account for.

Example Use Case: `cp folder1/file.gdoc folder2/file_1.gdoc`